# How to remove dbo.AspNetUserClaims and dbo.AspNetUserLogins tables (IdentityUserClaim and IdentityUserLogin entities)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

Our application doesn't need the excessive "Logins" and "Claims" functionality that identity uses. It would be nice if these tables simlpy didn't get created in the database, but I don't want to have to reimplement all identity classes...

I'd assume it's something like

```
public ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
        [...]

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Ignore<IdentityUserClaim>();
            modelBuilder.Ignore<IdentityUserLogin>();
        }
}
```

You would think this works according to the function descriptions, but it doesn't. The `AspNetUserClaim` and `AspNetUserLogins` tables still get created.

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: You could do just that: ignore them. There's nothing 'excessive' about having 2 empty tables in a db.

Comment: @Slight The first part of your comment is entirely not constructive.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is an implementation of `ApplicationDbContext`'s `OnModelCreating` method for your case. In fact it's just `IdentityDbContext`'s `OnModelCreating` method with ignoring of `IdentityUserClaim` and `IdentityUserLogin` entities.

**Note that `OnModelCreating` override should not invoke `base.OnModelCreating` method.**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Needed to ensure subclasses share the same table
        var user = modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .ToTable("AspNetUsers");
        user.HasMany(u => u.Roles).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId);
        user.Ignore(u => u.Claims);
        user.Ignore(u => u.Logins);
        user.Property(u => u.UserName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(256)
            .HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("UserNameIndex") { IsUnique = true }));

        // CONSIDER: u.Email is Required if set on options?
        user.Property(u => u.Email).HasMaxLength(256);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>()
            .HasKey(r => new { r.UserId, r.RoleId })
            .ToTable("AspNetUserRoles");

        var role = modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>()
            .ToTable("AspNetRoles");
        role.Property(r => r.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(256)
            .HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("RoleNameIndex") { IsUnique = true }));
        role.HasMany(r => r.Users).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId);

        modelBuilder.Ignore<IdentityUserLogin>();
        modelBuilder.Ignore<IdentityUserClaim>();
    }
}
```

Here are the relevant lines of code:

```
user.Ignore(u => u.Claims);
user.Ignore(u => u.Logins);
modelBuilder.Ignore<IdentityUserLogin>();
modelBuilder.Ignore<IdentityUserClaim>();
```

As required, it would result in the following migration without `dbo.AspNetUserClaims` and `dbo.AspNetUserLogins` tables:

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.AspNetRoles",
    c => new
        {
            Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
            Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 256),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
    .Index(t => t.Name, unique: true, name: "RoleNameIndex");

CreateTable(
    "dbo.AspNetUserRoles",
    c => new
        {
            UserId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
            RoleId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.UserId, t.RoleId })
    .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetRoles", t => t.RoleId, cascadeDelete: true)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: true)
    .Index(t => t.UserId)
    .Index(t => t.RoleId);

CreateTable(
    "dbo.AspNetUsers",
    c => new
        {
            Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
            Email = c.String(maxLength: 256),
            EmailConfirmed = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
            PasswordHash = c.String(),
            SecurityStamp = c.String(),
            PhoneNumber = c.String(),
            PhoneNumberConfirmed = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
            TwoFactorEnabled = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
            LockoutEndDateUtc = c.DateTime(),
            LockoutEnabled = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
            AccessFailedCount = c.Int(nullable: false),
            UserName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 256),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
    .Index(t => t.UserName, unique: true, name: "UserNameIndex");
```

Comment: When I do this and attempt to register, I am getting the error message "The property 'Claims' on type 'ApplicationUser' is not a navigation property. The Reference and Collection methods can only be used with navigation properties. Use the Property or ComplexProperty method." when I call the UserManager.CreateAsync() method, any ideas why @Deilan

Comment: What is the purpose for ensuring subclasses? Why we want to use this ?user.Ignore(u => u.Claims);
user.Ignore(u => u.Logins);

Comment: @NivithaG The original question include these conditions so it's probably better to address your question to the topic starter.