# How to ignore AspNetUserClaims table using IdentityUser?

Tags: asp.net, ef-code-first, asp.net-identity

I would like to use IdentityUser, but I do not want to use Claims or Logins.
So, I would like to remove these tables from my database.
Based on some search, I implemented my database context (Code First) like this:

```
public class MainDb : IdentityDbContext
{
    (...)

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("User")
            .Ignore(x => x.AccessFailedCount)
            .Ignore(x => x.Claims)
            .Ignore(x => x.EmailConfirmed)
            .Ignore(x => x.LockoutEnabled)
            .Ignore(x => x.LockoutEndDateUtc)
            .Ignore(x => x.Logins)
            .Ignore(x => x.PhoneNumberConfirmed)
            .Ignore(x => x.TwoFactorEnabled);

        modelBuilder.Ignore<IdentityUserLogin>();
        modelBuilder.Ignore<IdentityUserClaim>();
    }
}
```

When I try to create a migration ("Add-Migration Users" in Package Manager Console), I get the following error:

```
The navigation property 'Claims' is not a declared property on type 'IdentityUser'. Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from the model and that it is a valid navigation property.
```

If I remove the lines referencing Claims and Logins, the migration is created, with the other properties ignored:

```
public class MainDb : IdentityDbContext
{
    (...)

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("User")
            .Ignore(x => x.AccessFailedCount)
            .Ignore(x => x.EmailConfirmed)
            .Ignore(x => x.LockoutEnabled)
            .Ignore(x => x.LockoutEndDateUtc)
            .Ignore(x => x.PhoneNumberConfirmed)
            .Ignore(x => x.TwoFactorEnabled);
    }
}
```

I also tried to override Claims in my User class (child of IdentityUser) adding the set accessor, but it is not possible to add a new accessor on overriding.

According [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28948309/how-to-remove-dbo-aspnetuserclaims-and-dbo-aspnetuserlogins-tables-identityuser), which is an answered similar question, it seems that this was possible once, but now I am not able to find a solution.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: What is the point of spending a lot of time in removing something that you are not going to use anyway? it is only 2 tables, they take no space.

Comment: @trailmax It is trash in the database, and I would like to avoid it.